# Does Chrome have a SSL Certificate Verification setting equivalent like in Postman?

Tags: angular, google-chrome, ssl, postman, angular8

Sorry if this sounded odd. I'll try to explain my question.

I am working with a server overseas. When I first sent a request trough Postman, I got "Could not get any response" Error. This error was fixed after I turned off the "SSL Certificate Verification" on Postman.

I am using Angular 8 and when I send a request I got the Error below.

"Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://xxx/api/auth' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

I was thinking it should be something related to SSL Certificate. How can I fix this?

Comment: *"I was thinking it should be something related to SSL Certificate."* - It is not. You are doing a cross origin request (from localhost to xxx) and the CORS policy of the server (xxx) does not allow this. For more [read about CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).

Comment: I know it is related to the server but I don't have access to the server at the moment. I used a chrome extension and it works for now. I know it's temporary, I just need to work for the development process.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get around by using a Chrome Extension called Acces-Control-Allow-Origin.